# C# Discord how to wait for a message with prefix, then respond to it

Tags: c#, server, bots, discord

So I've been trying to write a Discord bot for my server which waits for a user input, then responds. I am trying to input "~ban user name#0000" and it ban the user, but I can't seem to find anything to get it working, is there anybody who can help me with the code for it. I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a method on the guild

SocketGuild.AddBanAsync()